# Padding top not working in ionic 3

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

The below is the html code for an ionic page. I am trying to apply padding and adjust the location of the content. In some places it is not working.

I want the login form to be located further down in the screen. Changing the values of  `<div padding-top="100px">`(line 10 in the code)
is not doing anything. How to correct this?

> Login.html

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar color="primary">
  <div class="row">
   <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </div>
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
   <div padding-top="100px">
      <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="loginUser()" novalidate padding id="loginForm">
          <ion-item id="loginItem_1">
          <ion-label stacked id="loginLable">Email</ion-label>
          <ion-input #email formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email address"
    [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.email.valid &&
      loginForm.controls.email.dirty" color="secondary">
          </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.email.valid  &&
  loginForm.controls.email.dirty" id="loginItem">
          <p id="loginLable">Please enter a valid email.</p>
</ion-item>

<ion-item id="loginItem_2">
  <ion-label stacked id="loginLable">Password</ion-label>
  <ion-input #password formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password" color="secondary">
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>

<button ion-button block type="submit" id="loginButton">
  Login
</button>
</form>
</div>

  <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToResetPassword()">
     I forgot my password 
  </button>

   <button ion-button block clear (click)="createAccount()">
     Create a new account
   </button>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
 <ion-toolbar color="primary">
  <ion-title>Created By</ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

> View

[image]

Comment: The `padding-top` attribute does not accept anything, it defaults to 16px of padding and can be overridden by changing `$content-padding` scss attribute. [See here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#element-padding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline CSS needs to be defined in the [style HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) like so:

```
<div style="padding-top: 100px;">
```

There is no "padding-top" attribute hence why it's not doing anything

I would recommend giving that div an id / class and targeting it with CSS instead, makes it easier to manage (Ionic comes with basic styling by default)

Comment: Your inline css works perfectly. But giving an id and then writing css does not work here. I tried it before also. I don't know why. <div id="loginDiv"> . In login.scss ->      #loginDiv{
        padding-top: 100px;
      }

Comment: I think that will depend on the setup of your project and where it sits, when you add the CSS def and inspect can you see it anywhere?

Comment: I had written the css for the div inside brackets of a child element. Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: Actually there is a `padding-top` attribute in Ionic. [See here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#element-padding)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `inline styles`. Which is very very BAD.

You can try as shown below.

*page.html*

```
 <div class="padding-top-100">

  </div>
```

*page.scss*

```
.padding-top-100 {
   padding-top:100px;
}
```

Comment: Then you can use `!important`

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
<ion-content padding="true">
```

You can see the example on this website :

http://ionicframework.com/getting-started